# Node js allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin for all domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I'm currently working on a node js / react api, i had 
the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error and fixed it.
My code currently look like this :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();});
```

Now i would like to authorize access to every domain, everybody whose connected can do the GET, POST... request, how could i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();});
```

Im not really sure that will work.
If it doesn't work and you want the most simplest solution try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: This can result in cross site request forgery.